# How to use the Override - XML Schema

Tags: xsd

I am trying to change/modify the element under the complexType by using override, I follow the example using the override tag [example](https://www.liquid-technologies.com/Reference/XmlStudio/XsdEditorNotation_Override.html). but I still have the issue of using it. I keep returning error. Can you help?

Thanks you.

[image]

Comment: Please do **not** post code as images. See here for more details why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551

Comment: Hi, my purpose was screenshot my error. that code is in the sample link is in my description.